# Auto Signing to Microsoft Teams using email and password

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, sandbox

I am developing a sandbox experience for my Microsoft Teams App. My requirement is that I want users to join my Microsoft Teams Channel without manually entering their username and password. For that, I have done this.

1. Created a user in my tenant using Graph API (username and password)
2. Assigned license and added to the pre-created team

Now I want to login to Microsft Teams with the username and password using the API and redirect the user to Microsft Teams.

Looking for help.

Comment: I am creating the user in my tenant and have access to the username and password of the user created. I want to mimic the steps through Microsft Graph API that the user would follow to log in to Microsoft Teams.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, no such API or PowerShell command is there to do this.